# Find permission of specific account and owner to replace with new account

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, filesystems, icacls

Using Windows 2008R2.
I have an ad account "fileadm" which have some permissions of many folders and files and for some it's a owner.
I need to replace this account with another account (with the same permission) and change owner.
I found the command iacls, and it's perfect to add or remove the permission of account, but I didn't find how find and replace the old account by the new account with the same permission and change owner.

I tested this command just to add a permission and it's ok :

icacls "D:\test12" /grant "domain\newadmfile":(OI)(CI)F /T

Answer (score 0):

You can use `takeown` for this on an elevated `cmd` prompt.

Comment: I think that takeown is the same as iacls but how do to find specific owner and replace it automatically by another account when the script find this specific owner ?

Comment: No it's not the same. If you want to replace the owner automatically for a given share or whatever you should write a script, your best bet would be PowerShell in this case.

Comment: Also: if the "new" account is also an AD account and has the same permissions, what's the purpose of this exercise? Couldn't you just simply rename the `fileadm` account? ;)

Comment: The purpose is to replace old account by new account which have inherit of the same permission of security of the file or/and folder.